# Data sent from one Vue component to another remains reactive

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have an input-component which has a form which collects start and finish times, job number and a select option.

This is attached to a data property with v-model.

This is then emitted with Event.$emit('addedData', this.hours)

In the display-component the Event.$on takes this data and checks an attribute and based on the check adds it to another data property (array) with this.todays_hours.push().

The template then displays this reactively using v-for in the template.

To this point all works fine.  However when I then attempt to add another line of hours the hours already displayed change reactively with the input.

As my input-component also posts to a database with axios if I reload the page all is displayed correctly.

input-component

```
<template>
   <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <input hidden="" v-model="hours.day">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2" >
                <input type="time" v-model="hours.start">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2" >
                <input type="time" v-model="hours.finish">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2" >
                <input type="number" v-model="hours.job_number">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2" >
                <select v-model="hours.climbing">
                    <option selected="selected" value="0">No</option>
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2" >
                <button @click="onSave" class="btn-success btn-sm">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'InputHoursComponent',

        props: ['employeeId', 'dayCheck', 'weekEnding'],

        data() {
            return {
                hours: {
                    start: "",
                    finish: "",
                    job_number: "",
                    climbing: 0,
                    day: this.dayCheck
                },
                climbing_select: ['No', 'Yes'],
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onSave()
            {
                axios.post('/payroll', {
                    employee_id: this.employeeId,
                    week_ending: this.weekEnding,
                    start: this.hours.start,
                    finish: this.hours.finish,
                    job_number: this.hours.job_number,
                    climbing: this.hours.climbing,
                    day: this.dayCheck
                })
                .then(response => {})
                .catch(e => {this.errors.push(e)});

                let data = this.normalizeProp(this.hours, s, true)
                Event.$emit('onAddedEntry', data);

                console.log("passed data:", this.hours);


            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

display-component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in todays_hours">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div hidden="" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2" >
                    <div v-text="item.start"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2" >
                    <div v-text="item.finish"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2" >
                    <div v-text="item.job_number"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2" >
                    <div v-text="(item.climbing)?'Yes':'No'"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2" >
                    <button @click="onEdit" class="btn-warning btn-sm mb-1">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'DisplayHoursComponent',

        props: ['dayCheck', 'hoursWorked'],

        data() {
            return {
                hours_list: this.hoursWorked,
                todays_hours: []
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.hours_list.length; i++) {
                if (this.hours_list[i].day === this.dayCheck) {
                    this.todays_hours.push(this.hours_list[i])
                }
            }

            Event.$on('onAddedEntry', (check) => {
                if(check.day === this.dayCheck){
                    this.todays_hours.push(check);
                }
            })
        },

        methods: {
            onEdit()
            {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image: Front end]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You could change the architecture of the components: Have one component (e. g. `WorkHoursComponent.vue` which contains 1 "InputHoursComponent" and 1 "DisplayHoursComponent". You then use the "WorkHoursComponent" as often as needed (1 component would be 1 section with 2 rows in your example) in the view. This makes the data per section (input data & display data) "private" per day.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have explained my issue.  I'm trying to stop any consecutive entry updating the entries already made in the display-component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pushing a copy of `check` instead of `check` itself.

```
Event.$on('onAddedEntry', (check) => {
  if(check.day === this.dayCheck){
    this.todays_hours.push({...check});
  }
})
```

You could also make the copy when you emit the event instead.

Comment: You are a genius.  Thank you.